# Chrome browser (windows 11): how to prevent users to change any color: background etc

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-11

In one school's computer classroom, it became necessary to prevent any student from changing any color of the Chrome browser. How to do this? After a web search I found that it would be possible to do this by adding Chrome policies (downloadable from the site) and setting the same appropriately. This is the article I followed: [Article](https://www.anoopcnair.com/configure-chrome-group-policy-admx-templates/?unapproved=596453&moderation-hash=670bbf79342833bc41602eec0965e825#comment-596453) My attempt led to an error;

> Could not find an appropriate resource file for file
> Windows(C:)\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\chrome.adx (error 2); The
> specified file could not be found.

the same error is displayed for the file: google.admx, two times both. So the policies for Chrome are not available as would be expected in the Group Policy after instal. Are there settings or a free app that allows this?